# i want to get max value in to 2 colomn in mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to know how to get max value ini 2 colomn ini mysql, for example data like this :

table_a :
Filed :
value 1, value2,value 3

and i want to get max value between value1,value2,value3 form table_a .

please somebody can help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the GREATEST() function:

```
SELECT GREATEST(value2, value2, value3);
```

But to get absolute maximum from all the rows, you may use:

```
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(value1), MAX(value2), MAX(value3)) FROM table_a;
```

Comment: It is my pleasure :)

Comment: how about AVG ? can u help me ? hehe

Comment: Post another question with details